# Drawing/specification for direct mount rear derailleur hangers?

Tags: derailleur, derailleur-hanger, hanger

I am currently designing a custom direct mount rear mech hanger for my bike (as one doesn't currently exist). I've successfully designed and built a standard mount using [PVD's Framebuilder Wiki](https://www.peterverdone.com/wiki/index.php?title=Shimano_Framebuilder_Info). However I've not had any success finding the same information  to allow me to design a [direct mount](https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/technologies/component/details/direct-mount-rear-derailleur.html) version. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: This may be helpful: https://wheelsmfg.com/

Comment: Same question here..  I know I can measure but why isn't the standard (or something approaching it) *anywhere* online?

Answer (score 1):

If you've got a design for a regular hanger, then you can measure a B-link and integrate it into your existing design. 3D printing helps greatly for testing the fit. I know that's not much to go with, but that's basically how I designed my DM hanger (had to reverse-engineer the stock one first too). Email me at klaster1+bse@gmail.com and I'll send you all the CAD files, maybe this will help.

If you didn't already, you might want to check [Velofrezer](https://velofrezer.com), they have a good hanger library and I even donated my design to them. Not sure if they ship out of Russia at the moment, with the war going on and whatnot.